# Drive doesn't open's pdf

Tags: android, pdf, google-drive-api, android-9.0-pie, android-10.0

**Usecase:** Open pdf(present in internal storage in my app name directory) in android via any pdf reader app present in the device (eg: GDrive).

```
     intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
       context.startActivity(intent);
```

**Problem** As per my current analysis it works fine in android 9 and below devices but creates the problem in Android 10.

**What is happening:** Pdf name gets displayed in Gdrive pdf viewer header but pdf doesn't render. and brings back to my app.

**Devices which are creating a problem:** Samsung s 10(Doesnot know the android version),  One plus A6000(Android 10), Samsung A70(Doesnot know the android version), Nokia 6.1 plus(Android 10), OnePlus 6T(Doesnot know the android version)

Though there are devices which are running on android 10 and are not creating a problem.

**Devices which are not creating a problem:**  Samsung GalaxyS20(Android 10)

There are also few devices that were not creating a problem earlier with android 10 and recently have started creating the problem and vice-versa also(i.e. problem got fixed automatically).

This problem is quite confusing and I am unable to find root cause.

**What I have tried**
 1. Checked Logs: No error/exception got logged

2. Checked result code of intent there also no issue.
3. Permissions: *In-app:* Media, camera, and storage 
                permission: enabled
                *In drive:* Storage permission: enabled

I have also read the documentation of android 10.

> To allow other apps to access files stored in this directory within internal storage, use a FileProvider with the FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION attribute.

```
     intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```

4. There is no problem with pdf because opening same pdf with some other pdf reader(eg: adobe)it works flawlessly.

Currently app

```
   compileSdkVersion 28
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
```

I just simply want to solve this issue. I am having a few questions:

1. Is it actually some problem with android 10 or issue with my code only?
2. Does making app compatible with android 10 will solve this issue?
3. How can I debug it?

If I have missed any case then please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a FileProvider.

Comment: Your intent should not work below Q/10 either. It should give a FileUriExposedException.

Comment: Thanks issue was due to not using file provider

Answer (score 1):

Although it is actually already answered by using FileProvider, I still would like to share the implementation using FileProvider to fix drive pdf reader issue. Here is how,

1 - **Add xml folder and create path.xml**
[image: add xml folder]

2 - **Add the following code in path.xml to configure file access within directory**

I set the pdf file location in downloads directory

```
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

3 - **Add meta data in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
   ...>
        {...}
        <provider
            android:authorities="com.example.myapplication"
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
</application>
```

4 - **Read pdf file using intent action**

```
var uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
      this, "com.example.applicationid", File(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
          .toString() +
                "/" + "yourfile.pdf"
      )
    )
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
var builder = StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()
StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build())
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
startActivity(intent)
```

Run application & try to open it using drive pdf viewer and voila! hope helps everyone!